# Add url in radio button description in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I´m adding a radio button in my UI and would like to add a URL that references the desired normalization method.

For example the deseq method would have a URL (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25516281) that points to the paper describing the method. How can i add the URL to the radio button ??

```
sidebarPanel(

         radioButtons("norm_method", label = h3("Select normalization method:"),
         choices = list("DESeq (Estimate variance-mean dependence (uses negative binomial distribution)"= "deseq", 
                        "CSS"= "css"),
                        selected = "deseq"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `choiceNames` and `choiceValues` method, rather than a named list for `choices`. For example,

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("norm_method", 
                   label = h3("Select normalization method:"),
                   choiceNames = list(
                     HTML("DESeq <a href = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25516281'>(Link)</a>"), 
                     "CSS"),
                   choiceValues = list("deseq", "css"),
                   selected = "deseq")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
```

would give you

[image]

See the examples at http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/radioButtons.html.